# Rails modifies input field as I don't want to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

It is really weird, but when I add in my Model:

```
serialize :source, Array
```

The input field by default has "**[]**" symbols inside any time you load page.

When I remove serializing, it disappears. But the code in the view itself is not modified, so I have no idea how to remove this brackets.

It's really annoying, please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize

> Active Record can serialize any object in text columns using YAML. To do so, you must specify this with a call to the class method serialize. This makes it possible to store arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects without doing any additional work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end
```

I suppose, you have in your view something like `<%= @my_model.source %>`.

Now if you remove `serialize :source, Array` from your model, the type of `@my_model.source` is string and  your view outputs an empty string (nothing).

If you add `serialize :source, Array` to your model, the type of `@my_model.source` is array. The empty array converted to the string during `<%= @my_model.source %>` is exactly, what you see: `[]`.

> It's really annoying, please, help me.

In order to help you, I need to know, what you exactly want to archive.

- Should `source` be a string, remove `serialize :source, Array` and be happy
- Should `source` be an array, rewrite your view to output the array iterating over it's elements. For example:

  ```
  <%- @my_model.source.each do |v| -%>
      <li><%= v %></li>
  <%- end -%>
  ```

Comment: thanks... I need user to input string, which rails converts to array. Just added another column, which is serialized, takes input from source and saved as array